# How to get the symbol and everything between the symbol

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been trying to capture anything with a symbol('!') and the word(s) and  between them is a space.

Example:

```
!!! !!! intense beatdown
```

Right now I could only get the `!!! intense` word but what would I want is to get the whole word:

```
!!! intense beatdown
```

Here is the regex that I'm using:

```
text = '!!! !!! intense beatdown'

matches = re.findall(r'(\!+ \w+)', text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 1 or more exclamation marks followed by matching 1+ word chars.

Then repeat a non capturing group 0+ times matching 1+ word chars separated by a space.

```
!+ \w+(?: \w+)*
```

In parts

- `!+` Match 1+ times `!`
- `\w+` Match a space and 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\w+` Match a space and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times using `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYjXFz/1)

Comment: Copying my reply below maybe this might be clear im trying to capture a symbol(!) and whitespace and the text. I think this also captures the extra (!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex :
**Regex :**

```
!!!\s([!\s]+.+)
```

[image]

**Demo Code :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/WetSpeedyDevice)

**Demo Regex :** [Here](https://regex101.com/r/8n9tya/3)

Comment: but this include the other '!!!' which i dont need maybe one match of a symbol (!) followed by a whitespace and the words. (`!!! intense beatdown`)